# Les variétés parlées au Québec sont-elles vraiment plus conservatrices ?

Tags: histoire, québec

J'ai déjà entendu plusieurs fois des Français et des Québécois dire que le français du Québec est plus proche du français du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle qu'est le français européen standard. Est-ce que c'est vrai, ou est-ce que les deux variétés ont changé autant, mais dans des sens différents ?

Comment: En tout cas, ça m'est arrivé plusieurs fois de comprendre ou de m'expliquer des québécismes *a posteriori*, en découvrant des archaïsmes du français, ou bien en faisant des fouilles étymologiques. Je serais bien curieux de savoir ce en hexagonal dont un québecois dirait « ça fait longtemps qu'on ne dit plus comme ça, nous ». Ce sont mes deux *sous*, mais ils répondent **oui**.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks, il est probable qu'une bonne partie de ces évolutions non présentes en français soient classées sous le terme d'anglicismes.

Comment: Autrement dit, le français serait plus proche du vieux français en ce qu'il a gardé certains termes originels, plutôt que de les remplacer par des anglicismes, comme l'ont fait les québecois ? Oui, ça se tient. Mais je ne sais pas si « se rapprocher de l'anglais » compte comme une variation originale d'une langue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

J'ai entendu la même allégation plusieurs fois, mais je dirais que les deux variétés ont évolué de façon différente. En visionnant un vidéo d'une allocution de Jean Lesage en 1960, je peux dire qu'il y a eu une évolution de la prononciation au Québec au cours des cinquante dernières années, alors je ne vois pas comment on aurait pu conserver le même français qu'au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Ceci dit, il y a quelques aspects que le français québécois a conservé que le français européen n'a plus. Mireille Huchon, dans son ouvrage *Histoire de la langue française* note ceci :

> [Le français québécois] a conservé la prononciation `/wɛ/` pour *oi*, le roulement du `/r/`, le maintien du `/t/` final, l'opposition du `/a/`d'avant et du `/ɑ/`d'arrière. Il y a tendance à l'allongement des voyelles accentuées dans les syllabes fermées par `/r/`, `/v/`, `/ʒ/`, à la diphtongaison des voyelles centrales et des voyelles nasales, à la disparition de `/i/`, `/y/`et `/u/` non accentués, à l'ouverture de `/o/` en `/a/`, à la palatalisation de `/t/` et `/d/` devant voyelles fermées.

Le français québécois est également très influencé par l'anglais, surtout côté lexique.

Huchon décrit également le français de la Renaissance, aux environs du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle. Voici une liste de ses particularités et évolutions du moyen français :

- Il y a existence du `/λ/` (qui se réduit à `/j/`au XIXe siècle).
- Le `/r/` est roulé.
- La double articulation nasale (voyelle + consonne) est réduite soit par dénasalisation de la voyelle lorsqu'elle est intervocalique (*bonne*, autrefois prononcé `/bɔ̃nɘ/`, se prononce `/bɔnɘ/`), soit par chute de la consonne lorsqu'elle est nasale et dernier élément de la syllabe (*bon*, autrefois prononcé `/bɔ̃n/`, se prononce `/bɔ̃/`).
- Le *h* aspiré articulé dans les mots d'origine francique devient muet.
- le sigmatisme (passage à `/z/`) affecte le `/r/` populaire.
- Les diphtongues et les triphtongues sont réduits, à l'exception de prononciations régionales.
- Le `/ə/` tend à disparaître. Il n'est plus prononcé à l'intérieur des mots après une voyelle (*vraiement* évolue en *vraiment*, mais nous gardons *gaiement*), il n'est plus prononcé en finale derrière une voyelle qu'en poésie et disparaîtra derrière une consonne au XVIIe siècle.
- Il y a une tendance à prononcer les *e*, *o* et *oe* ouverts ou fermés en fonction de leur place dans la syllabe; fermé en finale et ouvert devant consonne (*pere* `/perə/` passe à `/pɛrə/`).
- Il y a une prononciation populaire `/ar/` pour `/ɛr/` et *ian* pour *ien*.
- Certaines personnes ne prononcent pas la consonne finale des mots se terminant en *il*.
- Toutes les consonne finales sont lourdes (*David* rime avec *vit*), mais établissement de sonores au lieu de sourdes qui sont conservées dans la prononciation en liaison (*grand enfant*).
- L'influence de l'orthographe sur la prononciation est importante; par exemple, *digne* ou *maligne*, prononcés avec `/n/`, vont l'être avec un *n* mouillé `/ɲ/`.

Il y a bien entendu d'autres changements qui ont eu lieu au cours des siècles subséquents ou même antérieurs, et il est difficile de tous les énumérer de façon concise. Aucune langue vivante n'est statique. Certaines variétés changent plus rapidement que d'autres et sur des points différents.

Le français québécois et le français européen standard ont tous deux évolués à partir du français du XVIe siècle, environ. Si le français québécois a changé sur le point X, il n'a pas changé sur le point Y. Inversement, le français européen standard a peut-être changé sur le point Y, mais n'a pas changé sur le point X. Si l'on compare les trois français sur le point Y, alors le français québécois est plus conservateur, mais si le point de comparaison est autre, la conclusion différera, à mon avis.

---

**Sources**

En plus de l'ouvrage de Mireille Huchon, *Le français dans tous les sens* de Henriette Walter est une bonne source sur l'évolution du français, quoique un peu désuète, surtout en France, mais les deux livres abordent le français dans le reste de l'Europe, en Afrique, en Amérique du Nord et dans les Antilles.

Huchon, Mireille. *Histoire de la langue française*, Le livre de poche, Paris, 2002, 315 p.

Walter, Henriette. *Le français dans tous les sens*, Éditions Robert Laffont, collection Le goût des mots, Paris, 1988, 446 p.

Answer (score 6):

C'est une remarque qui se fait souvent en linguistique, on affirme que les variétés « régionales / périphériques / dialectales » sont censément plus conservatrices. À mon avis, c'est du relativisme mal placé. Après tout, personne ne décrit le français européen comme étant plus conservateur sous prétexte que le pronom *elle* n'y est jamais réduit en *a*, que la diphtongaison des voyelles longues et l'assibilation des occlusives dentales devant *i* et *u* n'en font pas partie ou qu'on n'y emploie pas des termes apparus au Québec comme *piton* (bouton), *fif* (homosexuel) et *séraphin* (avare) ! C'est une manière horriblement « chauviniste » (centralisant vers une variété de langue précise) de décrire un dialecte !

Il serait plus correct de dire que tout dialecte (qui par définition sera différent d'un autre, que l'autre forme de langage soit une forme de prestige ou pas) inclut forcément des innovations et des préservations. Dire qu'un dialecte en particulier est plus conservateur peut très rarement (en présumant que ce soit possible !), dans cette perspective, être appuyé par des faits vraiment concrets.

Answer (score 1):

effectivement ça choque un peu … sauf les titres de films traduits, et non pas laissés tels quels comme trop souvent en France métro' (quand ils ne sont pas remplacés par un autre titre en anglais !).

Cela dit, l'anglais (un peu moins l'allemand) emprunte fidèlement au latin, notre mère à tous, donc focusser et canceller ne me gênent en rien, comme i.e. ou e.g.. Défendons ce qui doit être défendu, il y a de quoi, mais évitons toute crispation excessive, n'est-ce pas ? À ce propos, « sponsor » est du latin pur, donc peut passer en français au lieu de donner à certains des coliques dues à leur manque de culture en langues anciennes. Idem pour les innombrables mots d'ancien français de l'anglais, qui nous reviennent en franglais avec leur sens archaïque, ce qui n'est pas ipso facto mauvais sauf s'ils sont mâtinés de germanique bien sûr.

Pour en revenir au français du Canada (je n'aime pas la réduction au Québec, Dieu merci il y a des francophones partout et même encore en Acadie), pour un « métro' » comme moi il apparaît effectivement pour le moins teinté d'archaïsmes du XVIIe siècle (il n'y avait pas grand monde au Canada au XVIe), et aussi de néologismes bien construits que nous empruntons à nos frères canadiens tels qu'oléoduc ou courriel. Donc vive la diversité et que les Canadiens francophones ne renoncent pas  à leurs spécificités ! Pour parler pédant, cela augmente la dimension diachronique du français, un peu comme les archaïsmes américains pour l'anglais. Il faut juste éviter les traductions littérales d'anglicismes dans la langue courante, ça fait désordre et c'est très moche.

Answer (score -3):

C'est vrai concernant la prononciation, et quelques délicieux mots désuets. L'accent si drôle des Québécois en français est en fait le français tel qu'on le parlait à l'époque de Louis XV.

Le comportement des francophones canadiens face au vocabulaire anglais est paradoxal. Les Québécois ont opposé une résistance farouche à quelques mots anglais que l'on utilise tout le temps en France depuis des décennies, comme *shopping*, *parking*, *week-end*, un *stop* sur la route. Ainsi, les francophones du Canada ont un *arrêt*, les fameux *magasinage* et *fin de semaine*… Ils ont même traduit *KFC*, en *PFK*, *Poulet Frit Kentucky* !

Mais le français canadien est surtout envahi par l'anglais. Par des mots anglais bien sûr, mais aussi par des tournures anglaises (mal) calquées en français. La voiture est un *char*, c'est drôle, mais le *char* a ses *wipers*, ses *brakes* et ses *tires*. Prononcés avec l'accent anglais, s'il vous plaît.

Ce qui est plus vicieux, ce sont les expressions calquées de l'anglais. Ainsi, le français canadien calque la tournure anglaise *they are here to stay* en *ces parcmètres sont là pour rester*. Pourquoi pas ? Le français canadien crée ainsi quelques tournures qui s'intègrent plutôt bien dans la langue française. Mais souvent, le résultat est franchement déplorable. Les anglicismes *appliquer (à un poste)* (*to apply*), *à date* au lieu d'*à ce jour*, *un autre dix minutes*, les horribles *focusser* et *canceller*… sont hélas courants — et j'en passe, et des pires.

Comment: Ceci est plus un jugement esthétique (pour ne pas dire une diatribe) qu'une vraie réponse à une question factuelle.