# Pronunciation of "oi" in French lyric diction

Tags: prononciation, musique

Where can I find a reminder of the rules for pronouncing "oi" in French lyric diction? I need to sing the word "voix", so I looked it up on Wiktionary, which unhelpfully gives both pronunciations ("/vwɑ/, /vwa/") without any explanation of when, where or how each pronunciation is used. Which would be correct for use in an art song?

Answer (score 4):

The rules for 'traditional pronunciations' were set down before the /a/ ~ /ɑ/ merger of modern Parisian French (around the 1930s). Hence the /wa/ ~ /wɑ/ merger is a consequence of that, and many modern books on lyric diction [maintain the distinction](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fWDMm3YokSAC&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q&f=false) but add that it is only found in "traditional" pronunciations.

In respected dictionaries, such as [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/), the options are presented, and I would take these as the major authority for lyric diction. The late 20th century work *[The Sounds of French](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=17jiE4jm-XUC&pg=PA64)* gives some rationale, but even then it is a bit random (basically, usually *-roi* will be /rwɑ/ and *-as* will be /ɑ/, except those that are not, such as verb forms and *bras* /bra/, and words ending in *-roire* /rwar(ə)/). Further rules such as suffixation will also cause /ɑ/ to change into /a/, e.g. *sable* with /ɑ/ to *sablonneux* with /a/.

One [1912](https://archive.org/details/frenchdictionfo00arnogoog/page/n51) primer for French diction gives for the *oi* combination just six words with /wɑ/: *bois*, *mois*, *noix*, *trois*, *pois* and *poids*.

There is a [limited amount of unanimity nowadays as to which belongs where](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=al0CrihFf7YC&pg=PA61), and I dare say that colouring the vowel while singing (for vocal quality and for intonation especially at the top of the range) would be more important [much like in Italian lyric diction].

So in essence, *aller chercher dans le dictionnaire* !

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already offer a wealth of information, but I wanted to provide some musical perspective. I'm not a singer by training, so the best that I can offer here is observations as a listener. In all of the songs and arias that come to mind, "oi" is pronounced with /a/ (or something that approximates it), not /ɑ/:

- "À cette voix": [Roberto Alagna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJTBItCBE0Q) (slightly ambiguous pronunciation to my ears though), [Leopold Simoneau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4eotSM9qL0)
- "C'est la mois des amants bénis": [Véronique Gens](https://youtu.be/dGPZ5-nBFoo?t=74), [Bruno Laplante](https://youtu.be/G26SHoIzEWM?t=41)
- "L'amour est un oiseau rebelle": [Elīna Garanča](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2snTkaD64U), [Clémentine Margaine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyaBCjJELAQ)
- "Sois calme, mon fils": [Camille Maurane](https://youtu.be/daquLR_7kmo?t=417)
- "Quand ta voix céleste prélude au silence des belles nuits": [Pierre Bernac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpH_fHzHRSM), [Pierre Boutet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ4uK98-8L0), [Nicolai Gedda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh_u1PfYUIU)

To the best of my knowledge, pronunciation in classical singing conforms relatively well to spoken pronunciation. There are IPA guides for some songs on websites such as SongHelix or Art Song Central. Music schools will also publish lists of resources such as [this one](https://voice.music.unt.edu/diction/singers), but you'll have to be careful. Not all resources may teach you accurate pronunciation. (I actually linked to one of them once as an example of common anglophone errors in French pronunciation.)

Answer (score 1):

In France the usual pronunciation of **oi** is /a/ as in [ʁwa], [vwa], [mwa].   The difference between /ɑ/ and /a/ is highly lost in contemporary French. What you can hear on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voix#Pronunciation) is [vwa]. On the [French side](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voix#Prononciation) they only give the [vwa] IPA transcription.

Hearing [vwɑ] in an opera would probably not disturb me, I might not even notice it. I don't know much about lyric diction but I presume you need to obtain the correct number of syllables, so pronouncing **oi** as two distinct syllables such as [vu.a] or [ʁu.a] would not surprise me either.

As a side note I want to point out that in Québec they still pronounce the letters **oi**  /wɛ/ as we used to do in France a few centuries ago.

Comment: the /ɑ ~ a/ distinction is only lost in European dialects (and maybe not even all of them). It is certainly well alive in Quebec (the final a of Canada is pronounced /ɑ/ here), though oi notoriously tends to move toward /we/, not /wɑ/.

Comment: @Circeus That's why I said in France, I did not want to speak for other European countries! Would you say **oi**  in Québec is more like /we/ than /wɛ/ as said [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2317/358) ?

Comment: I'm aware that the distinction between /ɑ/ and /a/ is disappearing in at least some areas, but it's alive and well if you're singing classical repertoire (or presumably if you're declaiming older drama or poetry). I guess the merging of those phonemes is part of the reason it's hard to check what the rules are (or used to be)! I have a dim memory of /ɑ/ after "r" (or possibly after "r" and "l"), /a/ elsewhere, but that may well be the opposite of what's correct... To me /vwa/ seems more likely anyway, and I'll happily take French Wiktionary as confirmation.

Comment: BTW I've tried looking at the edits of English Wiktionary to see who added a second pronunciation (and which that was), but I'm finding that much harder to do than on Wikipedia - can anyone else help with that?

Comment: Québecois pronunciation is apparently useful if you're singing French Baroque repertoire, so for example both _français_ and _François_ would have then been pronounced with /wɛ/, if I remember rightly...

Comment: @Counterpoise I don't know or want to advise on what would be best for your actual need, I suppose there's some sort of cohesion to respect within the whole work of art. There's a [Music SE site](https://music.stackexchange.com/), maybe you could seek help there. About English Wiktionary I have no idea how to tell you, but I'm going to ask the question on chat since you don't have enough reputation to do it, someone might know. I woul not know where on SE to ask for help about wikipedia or wiktionary.

Comment: Hmm... I fear that French lyric diction might be a considerably more esoteric topic in the context of music in general than in the context of French language! Thanks for asking on chat - let me know if you hear anything.

Comment: @Counterpoise The listing “/vwɑ/, /vwa/” on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voix comes from a [template](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:fr-IPA): the source says `{{fr-IPA|vwâ|voix}}`. You can search for the history on [Wikiblame](http://wikipedia.ramselehof.de/wikiblame.php?user_lang=en&lang=en&project=wiktionary&article=voix&needle=vw%C3%A2&skipversions=0&ignorefirst=0&limit=500&offmon=10&offtag=22&offjahr=2019&searchmethod=int&order=desc&force_wikitags=on&user=); here the parameters are a little tricky because you need to search the source, not the displayed text.

Comment: @Laure I could have sworn it didn't specify "France" when I answered. My bad. As far as I'm aware, the pronunciation /wɛ/ is not usual at all. My theory is that /ɛ/ moved to /e/ in final syllables except where it formed a minimal pair, which just wasn't the case with words in -ois. A few words moved all the way from /wa/ to /ɛ/ (froid, droit, always pronounced with a final /t/). The /we/ pronunciation remains mostly in moi and toi (possibly only there). Both that /we/ and the /ɛ/ pronunciation are strongly associated with joual, and so have somewhat negative/uneducated connotation.